# CUDA on Ubuntu 11.10 MacTel

Tags: 11.10, nvidia, cuda

Can anyone please point me to a tutorial or give me directions how to make my machine Cuda ready without crashing my system?

Tried it once with the Cuda guide on the Nvidia site but that is not for Ubuntu 11.10 and had to reboot the whole system.

Using Ubuntu 11.10 on a MacBook Pro released in 2009.

Comment: Hi , Have you gone through this ...http://laurencedawson.com/ubuntu-11.10-and-cuda-4.1

Comment: No I haven't. Will check it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 1 :

Add the CUDA 4.0 PPA.
`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:aaron-haviland/cuda-4.0`

Step 2 :

`sudo apt-get update`
`sudo apt-get upgrade`

64-bit :
`sudo apt-get install nvidia-cuda-gdb nvidia-cuda-toolkit nvidia-compute-profiler libnpp4 nvidia-cuda-doc libcudart4 libcublas4 libcufft4 libcusparse4 libcurand4 nvidia-current nvidia-opencl-dev nvidia-current-dev nvidia-cuda-dev opencl-headers`

32-bit :
`sudo apt-get install nvidia-cuda-gdb nvidia-cuda-toolkit nvidia-compute-profiler lib32npp4 nvidia-cuda-doc lib32cudart4 lib32cublas4 lib32cufft4 lib32cusparse4 lib32curand4 nvidia-current nvidia-opencl-dev nvidia-current-dev nvidia-cuda-dev opencl-headers`

Step 2a (Optional) :

If you do not have any nVidia driver installed before or you encounter any problem of booting up your system, you need to do the following command. Otherwise, this step is not required at all.

`sudo nvidia-xconfig`

**This step may not be required.

Step 3 :

Reboot your system.

Step 4 (Optional) :

To install SMPlayer.

`sudo apt-get install smplayer smplayer-translations smplayer-themes`

Then set it to use "vdpau" at "Output Driver" at "Preference".

Step 5 (Optional) :

Once installed the CUDA Toolkit and nVidia drivers, you can download the sample codes for testing.

`sudo apt-get install freeglut3-dev libxi-dev libXmu-dev`

`wget http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/4_0/sdk/gpucomputingsdk_4.0.17_linux.run`

`sudo chmod +x gpucomputingsdk_4.0.17_linux.run`
`./gpucomputingsdk_4.0.17_linux.run`

Accept the default settings.

`cd NVIDIA_GPU_computing_SDK/C`
`make`

** Please ignore the warning messages for unsupported gcc version. That is no harm at all.

Run the sample codes.

`cd NVIDIA_GPU_computing_SDK/C/bin/linux/release`
`./deviceQuery`
`./nbody`

[Info from this site](http://samiux.blogspot.com/2011/05/howto-nvidia-cuda-toolkit-40-on-ubuntu.html)